# Installing Redhawk on Ubuntu 20.04 Trying to start OmniOrb Services and it fails with the following error:

Tags: ubuntu, redhawksdr, omniorb

The omniOrbName Service fails too start with the following error:

```
cannot open /usr/bin/omniNames: error while loading shared libraries: libomniORB4.so.2

Also libomniORB4.so.2 is linked to libomniORB4.so.2.3

/usr/lib64/libomniORB4.s0.2 ==> libomniORB4.so.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed following these [intructions](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/omniorb) using `apt-get update -y` and `apt-get install omniorb omniorb-nameserver` and then just ran `omniNames -start` and it started up for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to connect my computer to the internet so I have to download and install these apps by first downloading the app and then converting them to .deb files so that I could install them on the local system.  I used the alien command to convert them to .deb files and then the dpkg file to install the .deb apps.  For examdple: sudo alien omniORB-servers-4.2.3.0.145273.e17.x86_64.rpm Then sudo dpkt -i omniorb-servers_4.2.3-1.145273_amd64.deb

Comment: I finally got it installed.  but when I type omiNames -start it gives me the following error: data file ' /var/lib/omniorb/omninames-epbo-lin-001.dat' exists.  Can't use -start option.